# Can I eager load a property using HQL?

Tags: nhibernate, select, hql, eager-loading

I'm trying to work out how to eager load the customers in the following HQL query:

```
select order.Customer
from Order as order
where order.Id in
(
  select itemId
  from BadItem as badItem
  where (badItemType = :itemType) and (badItem.Date >= :yesterday)
)
```

There's the usual many-to-one relationship between orders and customers.

I'd like to do this is in the query, as opposed to the mapping, if possible - as in a "join fetch..."

Maybe the query would be refactored as a join and I'm having a mental block.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
select customer
from BadItem as badItem
join fetch badItem.Order as order
left join fetch order.Customer as customer 
where (badItemType = :itemType) and (badItem.Date >= :yesterday)
```

For this to work you will need to add the relationship between BadItem and Order if BadItem is unrelated to Order, or use an `inner join` with extra conditions (watch out for performance when using alternative 2).

Alternative:

```
select customer
from Order as order
join fetch order.Customer as customer
where order.Id in
(
  select itemId
  from BadItem as badItem
  where (badItemType = :itemType) and (badItem.Date >= :yesterday)
)
```

EDIT:

What about:

```
select customer
from Order as order
join fetch order.Customer customer
join fetch customer.orders 
where order.Id in
(
  select itemId
  from BadItem as badItem
  where (badItemType = :itemType) and (badItem.Date >= :yesterday)
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm trying your "alternative" query first, but am getting a " Query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list" error. Any ideas? I'll try you first suggestion once I can work out how to map BadItem and Order (the key in the BadItems table is effectively three columns - not my design).

Comment: Hmm, It sound like the reason is that if you select the customers, they will be populated already. So that basically means that your questions is moot; if you select the customers directly, the customers cannot be lazy loaded (hibernate doesn't support lazy loading on attribute level) and are therefore already loaded. Could this be it?

Comment: One would have thought so, but my original query throws a LazyInitializationException for Customer._orders (_orders is the backing field for the Order property).

Comment: Yes. It's looking good now. Problem solved. Think I had another issue that was confusing things, but all sorted now.