# Hibernate data retrieve improvement.

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I eager load a property using HQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684376/can-i-eager-load-a-property-using-hql)

I will try to synthesize the issue by abstracting the real scenario.

I have **EntityA** which has **EntityB** as member and is lazily loaded.

**EntityB** has as well as member **EntityC**

What I do now is not very optimum

```
select distinct entA from EntityA entA ,EntityB entB, EntityC entC 
where entA.ent_B_ID = entB.id and entB.ent_C_ID = entC.id and entC.someValue ='x'
```

This will retrieve all **entityA** objects but I have to call on each of these objects **getEntityB** and on **entityB** **getEntityC** to have the full object ,so too many DB calls for this lazy loading.

Mention:I can't override mappings.

Before (years ago) I used JDBC and there with sql I would have done something similar but with HQL can I retrieve full **entityA** objects in 1 query ?

Thank you!

Comment: This seems similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684376.

Comment: this worked ok...select distinct entA from EntityA entA left join fetch entA.entityB left join fetch entA.entityB.entityC where
entA.entityB.entityC.someValue = '" + someValue + "'";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use in "fetch" or on the criteria or in the hql or you can set on the relation - lazy=false